# Why does ATI 5570 HD video card driver installation cause Windows 7 To Blue Screen?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod, amd-radeon

This one is for the hive mind. I have a brand new Dell Optiplex 760 workstation with 4 gigabytes of RAM running Windows 7 Professional (32bit). This is a new box with nothing installed other than what was provided for directly by Dell. I installed a Saphire ATI PCI Express 5570 HD. Upon trying to install the 10.4 Catalyst drivers the system will blue screen. It blue screens during the hardware detection phase of the installation process. I have already performed the following trouble shooting steps:

- Changed system RAM
- Installed only 2 gigabytes of RAM
- Installed different versions of
  Catalyst drivers (10.4 - 9.12)
- Tried to install video only component
  of driver (vs entire Catalyst suite)
- Made sure Windows 7 was fully updated
- Flashed mother board BIOS to current version
- Removed and re-seated video card
- Contacted ATI Support (We all know
  how this went......)
- Verified supply outputting properly

The blue screen error (via Windows BugCheck entry in event log) is a 0x000000CA and refers to a plug and play error most likely caused by a bad driver. The problem is that the driver installation process never gets far enough to actually install a driver. The resolution center in Windows provides a solution of installing the 10.4 Catalyst driver to resolve issue (which fails).

Looking for some alternate views to resolve.

Comment: "One for the hive mind"?, this isn't 4chan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution that worked for me follows:

I have a Sapphire ATI PCI Express 5570 as well and experienced the exact same 0x000000CA BSOD in Windows 7 when trying to install drivers for it.  I tried the Catalyst driver on Sapphire's website as well as on ATI's website.  I tried Catalyst version 10.4, 10.5, and 10.6 with the same issue.  I also tried updating the Optiplex (755) BIOS to A17 and trying various BIOS settings to no avail.  The BSOD always occurs when the Catalyst software tries to query the video card.

My work-around was to not let Catalyst query the card.  I wish it was as easy as an installation option to avoid the query in the Catalyst install, but of course it can't be that straight-forward.  Instead, I let the Catalyst software unzip itself to a location, located the driver .inf files in that location, and manually updated the video card driver (Device Manager->Update Driver->"Let me specify the best driver..."->specify location->etc).  Two identically named ATI 5570 drivers presented themselves in the driver selection window, so I chose the first one.

Then I manually installed the Catalyst Control Center by locating just the CCC install files unzipped by the ATI package (I ran two setups, CCC-core I think and another name that resembled CCC-something-or-other.  I am probably missing some minor components but the screen resolution, color depth, and CCC features all seem to work fine.

Basically everything works with the exception of some video card DLL warnings if I run the System Score test in Windows 7, though it does come back with what feels like an appropriate score of 5.9 for this card.

---

As a follow-up: after doing all of those steps the Catalyst Installer ran successfully. I did however end up having to delete the following files to make some lingering occasional errors go away:

```
c:\windows\system32\coinst.dll
c:\windows\system32\atiuxp64.dll 
c:\windows\syswow64\atiumdva.dll 
c:\windows\syswow64\atiumdva.cap
```

Answer (score 9):

To fix this:

1. Uninstall any ATI drivers on your system.
2. Run the CCC installer but I suggest canceling after it extracts the files.
3. Navigate to: C:\ATI\Support\10-x_vista64_wi n7_64_dd_ccc_enu\Config
4. EDIT InstallManager.cfg
5. Change WorkaroundInstall=false to WorkaroundInstall=true
6. Run Setup.exe and the CCC should install without a problem

Comment: Works for me. Aftermarket Radeon HD5570 - Sapphire iirc - in Dell Optiplex 755. Tested on Win7 x64 with 11.6 and 11.8 drivers.

Comment: I just tried this on an Optiplex 755 with a new ATI Radeon HD 5670, worked liked a charm. Wow. Good call.

Comment: I've been frustrated for days, getting BSOD over and over. And to think, changing one line did the trick! I wish HIS could have told me this. Thanks!! Dell Optiplex 780, HD 7750 Win 7 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem and I was finally able to fix it by following these steps
(without manipulating/deleting files from the original driver):

1. Uninstall all previous graphic drivers in device manager
   (delete the driver software for this device checked).
2. Repeat step 1 until the original Microsoft VGA driver is active.
3. Download and run "Guru3D - Driver Sweeper" and clean system from ATI/AMD drivers.
4. Update BIOS.
5. Install new drivers.

I'm not sure if the steps 1-3 or just step 4 did the trick (I guess it was step 4)... but
following these steps I was able to install a Radeon 3450 in a DELL PC.
No matter what I tried before caused the system to crash with 0x000000CA BSOD.
Modifying "InstallManager.cfg" didn't help much: No BSOD happening but driver installation just failed everytime!

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Launch Windows in Safe Mode
2. Uninstall previous driver
3. Reboot
4. Safe Mode Again
5. Install ATI Drivers
6. Reboot
7. ???
8. Profit

No seriously tho, safe-mode & manually uninstalling a previous driver go a long way for ATI. Also, make sure you're using the 32bit drivers if you're on win32.

Answer (score 0):

One other question I have is are you using the Driver from Dell or from ATI? If you are using the Dell supplied driver sometime ATI will put out a new release of a driver and Dell hasn't updated their drivers yet. Download your Driver from ATI. I assume you are double checking this but make sure it's for Win7 32 not x64 and not for Vista.

Comment: " Upon trying to install the 10.4 Catalyst drivers the system will blue screen." It never gets to a point where drivers are actually installed, yet simply reboots the system during the process. This is an after market add in card direct from ATI and I am using ATI drivers from website 10.4. Using 32bit drivers.

Comment: Does this card work in another machine? with Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem when trying upgrade ATI Catalyst from version 8.00.0873 to 8.00.0911 where I was getting a BSOD (Blue Screen) in Windows 7 x64 with an ATI Radeon 5450 every time setup was "detecting hardware configuration"

To solve I did

1. Uninstall any ATI drivers on your system.
2. Extract ATI catalyst to local folder by running downloaded EXE from ATI website
   (default location is fine `C:\AMD\Support\13-4_win7_win8_64_dd_ccc_whql`)
3. Cancel after extraction is completed and before setup asks for Language to continue
4. Browse to `C:\AMD\Support\13-4_win7_win8_64_dd_ccc_whql\Config`
5. EDIT `InstallManager.cfg` with notepad or similar text editor
6. Change `WorkaroundInstall=false` to `WorkaroundInstall=true`
7. Run `Setup.exe` and the CCC should install without a problem

Worked from me on 8/4/2013.